# Using The Riemann Zeta Functional Equation

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, complex-integration, mellin-transform

Riemann was able to establish the following link between the Riemann zeta function and the weighted prime counting function [$J(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html).
$$\ln(\zeta(s))=s\int_1^\infty J(x)x^{-s-1}dx$$
Using the [Mellin inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform), he then obtained the following:
$$J(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\ln(\zeta(s))}{s} x^{-s}ds$$
The problem with the above equation is that it evaluates $\zeta(s)$ at complex values. However, he was able to surmount that problem by using the [Zeta functional equation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Functional_Equation_for_Riemann_Zeta_Function), which states
$$\pi^{-s / 2} \Gamma \left({\frac s 2}\right) \zeta \left({s}\right) = - \frac 1 {s \left({1 - s}\right)} + \int_1^\infty \left({x^{s / 2 - 1} + x^{- \left({s + 1}\right) / 2} }\right) \omega \left({x}\right)dx$$
I understand how this formula is obtained, but cannot grasp this next step. From combining the functional equation and the result from the inverse Mellin transform, he obtains 
$$J(x)=Li(x)-\sum_\rho Li(x^\rho)-\ln(2)+\int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)\ln(t)}$$
How did the functional equation result in this simplification? How did Riemann simplify the complex integral? a step by step explanation from the Mellin integral to the final result above would be very helpful!

NOTE: I am not very familiar with integration over the complex plane, but very willing to learn.

Comment: What is the exact question? Is this a historical question about Riemann or a question about proofs of the Prime Number Theorem? Anyway, the question seems somewhat based on a false premise. (What is your source for the claims you make.) Most any book on analytic number theory should be able to clear this up.

Comment: @quid thanks for pointing that out - just edited the question

Comment: start with $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s \zeta(s)}$ you'll get with the residue theorem (and the functionnal equation to allow applying residue theorem on the contour $\Re(s)$ going to $-\infty$) a sum of $x^\rho$ for $\varphi(x)$, then remark that $\zeta'(s)/\zeta(s)$ is the derivative of $\ln\zeta(s)$ so that $J(x) = \int \varphi'(x)/\ln x$ and you'll get the $Li(x^\rho)$ terms... the integral in the right of the $Li(x^\rho)$ is a sum of $Li(x^{-2k})$ for the "trivial" zeros of zeta. my advice : read wikipedia, the Tichmarsh's book "the theory of the riemann zeta function" and forums and pdfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pleas look [this](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/keating.pdf) page 4  may you get what you want (P. Bourgade and J.P. Keating Seminaire Poincare)